# Generating Qt Bindings for .NET

Tags: .net, qt, binding, swig

I'm currently working on a project that using Qt C++ and the API is exposed to Python using SIP.  In order to make the program more attractive in the Windows environments I would like to expose the API to .NET.

I have found qt4dotnet although that is just Qt bindings, I need something to generate those bindings for my API.  I heard SWIG "might" be able to generate bindings for Qt apps although I can't seem to find any help on this.

Anyone know something that could help?

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth investigating [ActiveQt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/activeqt.html), and reading [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/activeqt-dotnet.html) document from Nokia that details integrating ActiveQt with the .NET Framework.

There's also a [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915289/how-to-map-qt-signal-to-event-in-managed-c-c-cli) which discusses wrapping Qt signals and slots (or generic methods) using Microsoft's C++/CLI extensions.

I'm not a .NET developer though, so I probably can't provide any more help than that.

Answer (score 0):

In the kdebindings module, we have proper [Qt bindings](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdebindings/csharp/qyoto) called Qyoto, based on our SMOKE library (a library shared by all our bindings, used to call C++ API, only depends on the STL).

Unfortunately the project is unmaintained as of now, due to lack of interest from *nix users.

However, it's very easy to extend SMOKE based bindings. You only need to generate a new SMOKE library from your own header files, a matching .NET assembly and write a Qyoto plugin.
Generating the SMOKE library is done with smokegen and I've written a [tool](https://gitorious.org/assemblygen) that generates .NET assemblies from SMOKE libraries (it hasn't been merged yet, however).

I guess that it will require some effort to bring the bindings up to date and actually make them work on Windows, but I think it's the best choice you have (if you don't want to hand-craft bindings). We already have support for all the QMetaObject stuff (including custom Signals, Slots, Q_PROPERTIES, Q_CLASSINFO, etc.) and extending the bindings is quite easy.

Regarding Windows, I've once got a Hello World working, but it seems that it isn't working anymore.

If you want to get involved, you can contact us at kde-bindings@kde.org or on #kde-bindings on Freenode.

P.S.: I would post more links, but the spam protection won't let me. You can find more information about SMOKE on projects.kde.org/smokeqt, projects.kde.org/smokegen and techbase.kde.org.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into some time in the future.