# Callback from QThread in unmanaged dll to managed c++ Main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, callback

I want to make a callback from a thread created in an native dll to my managed wrapper, I have successfully created my thread and made calls via Qt.s framework signals and slots.

How can I make a callback from a separate thread to the main thread between an unmanaged and managed dll? The unmanaged is done in QT c++ and the managed via VS c++.

Unmanaged dll:
main.cpp

```
typedef void (__stdcall * processCallback)(char*, int, int);
Thread* thread;
EXTEXPORT_VOID initdll(processCallback callback)
{
    /* Init MainThread - Runs eventloop */
    thread = new Thread(callback);
    thread ->start();
}
```

thread.h - The run method, I make my callback here but the callback continues in my new thread, and not the Main thread which created it in my managed dll. Why?

```
void run() {
    callback("Testing callback", 0, 0);
    exec();
}
```

I need this callback to be to my main thread and not in my now runningthread.

Managed dll

```
/* From unmanaged to managed c++ */
[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention::StdCall)] 
public delegate void UnmanagedCallbackDelegate(char*, int, int);

typedef void (__stdcall * typeCallback)(char*, int, int); //Same def as in Unm. dll
public ref class cDLLThreadWrapper
{
    [DllImport("cDLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention::StdCall)] 
    static void initdll(typeCallback);

public:
    typeCallback callbackNative;
    UnmanagedCallbackDelegate^ m_CallbackDelegate;

    cDLLThreadWrapper()
    {

    }
    void init()
    {
        m_CallbackDelegate = gcnew UnmanagedCallbackDelegate(this, &cDLLThreadWrapper::UnhandledCallback);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(m_CallbackDelegate);
        callbackNative = static_cast<typeCallback>(ptr.ToPointer());

        initdll(callbackNative);
    }
            void UnhandledCallback(char* data, int x, int y)
    {
        String^ callStr = gcnew String(data);
                    //AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId())
        //I get here but the thread is wrong, it should be the main thread
                    //which called the initdll function from this wrapper.
    }
}
```

As i said the callback works but I get it in the wrong thread for some reason, shouldn't the callback be from thread1 -> Main thread?

This is a very simplified example but the specific question is why my callback doesn't go from my newly created thread to the main thread but stays in the newly created thread. Where am I thinking wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing the concepts of callbacks and event loops - `thread1` is calling the function, so the code is executed in `thread1`.  Qt threads have [event loops](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq14-threading.html#perthreadeventloops) - does your main thread have something similar?  You want to post an event to the loop, not simply use a callback function.

Comment: I noticed I didn't mention this, I've referenced my wrapper dll in a .net form application and the application event loop is my "main thread" in this matter. I know how to use signal and slots between two qt threads but the problem is when I need to get from my unmanaged thread dll to my .net form application through my c++ wrapper. How can I post an event to my .net event loop from my qt dll, that's my question really?

Answer (score 1):

You are executing your callback as a direct call, what surprises you? If you do `callback(...)` in Qt, it would execute and continue in your new thread too. It's an equivalent of declaring signal-slot connection with `Qt::DirectConnection` type. Qt is clever and does `Qt::QueuedConnection` behind the scenes for you, when the caller thread and target thread are different. But in order for that to work automagically, the source must be declared as `signal`, the target must be declared as `slot`, and the target must be a `QThread`, having a Qt-specific event loop running. You have "some" event loop running in your managed C++, but Qt have no idea how and what to post there. Definitely not a `QObject` metadata, your .NET C++ won't understand it. Qt magic works only inside Qt. You must find out how specifically events are posted to your .NET C++ and teach your Qt code to do it. I am no .NET expert, but the following looks useful

[How to map Qt Signal to Event in Managed C++ (C++/CLI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915289/how-to-map-qt-signal-to-event-in-managed-c-c-cli)

Comment: Yes I noticed that of course, thanks for the link, looks promising. I noticed that I could do it in another way by Invoking the delegate in my .net forms application as well but I see your point.