# How to write wrapper classes for mapping Qt Signals to C# events (through C++/CLI)

Tags: c#, c++, qt, c++-cli

Calling C++/Qt classes through C++/CLI wrapper is a like a walk in the park.

But I'm stuck mapping C++/Qt signals to C# events.

I tried to combine some available how-tos/answers but did not get any working result:

- [How to map Qt Signal to Event in Managed C++ (C++/CLI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915289/how-to-map-qt-signal-to-event-in-managed-c-c-cli)
- [Calling managed code from unmanaged code and vice-versa](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice)
- and some other not so directly related...

The problem here is, that these how-tos/answers are quite old. I am currently working with Qt5.5 (soon 5.6) and .NET 4.6. I tried to adapt everything to current state of the art but may have failed.

It may be, that I can't see the forest because of too much trees, so I would like to ask for a **working** example which accomplishes the task with current framework versions, so that I can spot the differences and learn from the mistakes.

[edit] 
You can checkout this github repo, for this source. The parts for QtSignal to C#Event are commented out to have this code in a working state.

Github repo: https://github.com/qwc/QtSignalToCSharpEvent

For those who still want to read everything without playing around... read on...
Here my current non-working code:

So I have a class in pure Qt5

```
#ifndef PUREQT_H
#define PUREQT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include "PureQt_global.h"

class PUREQTSHARED_EXPORT PureQt : public QObject    {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PureQt(QString name);
    ~PureQt(){}
    QString getSomeVar();
    void someFunc(const QString & string);
public slots:
signals:
    void someFuncWasCalled(const QString &string);
private:
    QString someVar;
};

#endif // PUREQT_H
```

With the following rather simple implementation:

```
#include "PureQt.h"

PureQt::PureQt(QString name)    {
    this->someVar = "ctor("+name+")";
}

QString PureQt::getSomeVar()    {
    return this->someVar;
}

void PureQt::someFunc(const QString &string)    {
    this->someVar += "someFunc("+string+")";
    emit someFuncWasCalled(this->someVar);
}
```

Then I've implemented a managed wrapper with C++/CLI to be able to call the unmanaged code from C#. Be aware that I've already tried to add code to get signal to event management.

```
#pragma once
#include "conversion.h"
#include "../pureqt/PureQt.h"
#include "SignalProxy.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace ManagedCppQtSpace {

    // different variants... from tinkering around.
    delegate void someFuncWasCalled(String^);
    delegate void someFuncWasCalledU(QString str);

    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind::Sequential)]
    public ref struct DelegateWrapper {
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType::FunctionPtr)]
        someFuncWasCalledU^ delegate;
    };

    public ref class ManagedCppQt
    {
    public:    
        ManagedCppQt(String^ name){
            pureQtObject = new PureQt(StringToQString(name));
            proxy = new SignalProxy(pureQtObject);
            wrapper = gcnew DelegateWrapper();
            wrapper->delegate = gcnew someFuncWasCalledU(this, ManagedCppQt::signalCallback);
            signalCallbackProxy callbackproxy;
            Marshal::StructureToPtr(wrapper, callbackproxy, false); // currently im stuck here with a compile error, but the problem may lie somewhere else...
            proxy->setCallback(callbackproxy);
        };
        ~ManagedCppQt(){
            delete pureQtObject;
        };

        event someFuncWasCalled ^ someFuncCalled;

        void someFunc(String^ string){
            pureQtObject->someFunc(StringToQString(string));
        };

        String^ getSomeString() {
            return QStringToString(pureQtObject->getSomeVar());
        }

        void signalCallback(QString str) {
            someFuncCalled(QStringToString(str));
        }

        DelegateWrapper ^ wrapper;

    private:
        PureQt * pureQtObject;
        SignalProxy * proxy;
    };
}
```

So to link signal and slot handling from Qt with a callback which is able to raise an event in managed code some will need a proxy class when there's no option to change the basis code (because it's also used in other unmanaged C++ projects).

```
#ifndef SIGNALPROXY_H
#define SIGNALPROXY_H

#include <QObject>
#include "../pureqt/PureQt.h"

typedef void (*signalCallbackProxy) (QString str);

class SignalProxy : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SignalProxy(PureQt* pqt);
    ~SignalProxy();
    void setCallback(signalCallbackProxy callback);
signals:
public slots:
    void someFuncSlot(QString str);
private:
    PureQt* pureQt;
    signalCallbackProxy scallback;
};

#endif // SIGNALPROXY_H
```

With implementation:

```
#include "SignalProxy.h"

SignalProxy::SignalProxy(PureQt* pqt){
    pureQt = pqt;
    this->connect(pureQt, SIGNAL(PureQt::someFuncWasCalled(QString)), this, SLOT(someFuncSlot(QString)));
}

SignalProxy::~SignalProxy()
{}

void SignalProxy::setCallback(signalCallbackProxy callback){
    this->scallback = callback;
}

void SignalProxy::someFuncSlot(QString str){
    if(this->scallback != NULL)
        this->scallback(str);
}
```

So. Now, how to correctly link these two worlds, Qt signals -> managed .NET events?

I've also tried some simple approaches, which lead to compile errors, like:

```
QObject::connect(pureQtObject, &PureQt::someFuncWasCalled, &MangagedCppQtSpace::ManagedCppQt::signalCallback);
```

instead of the proxy class, or with a lambda function:

```
QObject::connect(pureQtObject, &PureQt::someFuncWasCalled, [] (QString str) {
    signalCallback(str);// or ManagedCppQt::signalCallback, but for this the method has to be static, and it isn't possible to raise events from static methods...
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is tripping you up? Are you getting compile errors? Runtime errors? No errors but the events aren't firing?

Comment: You need to do two things: 1. Declare the event handler as a member of your class. 2. Invoke the event handler from a slot (a lambda, really) connected to your signal. That's really all there's to it.

Comment: "could paste my current example code, but I think that would only confuse readers..." That's precisely what you need to do to keep this question on-topic. Otherwise, it's a direct duplicate.

Comment: @Kuba Ober could you further elaborate on your first comment, e.g. with a code example?

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is mixing Qt with C++ CLI. To have functional signal and slots you Qt needs process header files to generate own meta data. Problem is that tool will be unable to understand C++CLI features.

To overcome this problem first you have to do fallback to C++ interfaces and there perform safely C++ CLI operations.

So you need extra class like this which doesn't know .net and creates bridge to standard C++:

```
class PureQtReceiverDelegate { // this should go to separate header file
   virtual void NotifySomeFunc(const char *utf8) = 0;
};

class PureQtReceiver : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PureQtReceiver(PureQtReceiverDelegate *delegate, PureQt *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , mDelegate(delegate)
    {
        bool ok = connect(parent, SIGNAL(PureQt::someFuncWasCalled(QString)),
                this, SLOT(someFuncReceiver(QString)));
        Q_ASSERT(ok);
    }

public slots:
    void someFuncReceiver(const QString & string)
    {
        delegate->NotifySomeFunc(string.toUtf8().data());
    }
private:
    PureQtReceiverDelegate *delegate;
};
```

Now your C++CLI class should implement this `PureQtReceiverDelegate` and there convert string to .net version  and post notification.

Note you can/should forward declare Qt specific classes in C++CLI header file.

---

Above solution is good if you are using Qt4 od don't to use C++11.

If you are using Qt 5 and have C++11 available than there is more handy solution: you can use lambda expression in when making a connection to a QObject. So your `ManagedCppQt` can look like this:

header:

```
#pragma once
#include "conversion.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

// forward declaration
class PureQt;

namespace ManagedCppQtSpace {
    delegate void someFuncWasCalled(String^);

    public ref class ManagedCppQt
    {
    public:    
        ManagedCppQt(String^ name);
        ~ManagedCppQt();

        event someFuncWasCalled ^ someFuncCalled;

        void someFunc(String^ string);

        String^ getSomeString();

        void signalCallback(QString str);

    private:
        PureQt * pureQtObject;
    };
}
```

in cpp:

```
#include "../pureqt/PureQt.h"

using namespace ManagedCppQtSpace;

ManagedCppQt:ManagedCppQt(String^ name) {
    pureQtObject = new PureQt(QStringFromString(name));
    QObject::connect(pureQtObject, &PureQt::someFuncWasCalled,
                     [this](const QString &string){
                         if (this->someFuncCalled) {
                              String^ s = StringFromQString(string);
                              this->someFuncCalled(s);
                         }
                     });
}

ManagedCppQt::~ManagedCppQt(){
    delete pureQtObject;
}
```

This is much easier, faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: While I unfortunately had no time to test your solution, it is nicely explained, makes sense and looks promising. Since I won't be around here until after the bounty ends, I'll award it in advance.

Comment: How can I circumvent this compiler error using your last hint with a lambda: `ManagedCppQtSpace::ManagedQt::{ctor}::<lambda_{somehash}>: local class, struct or union definitions are not allowed in a member function of a managed class`

Comment: Using the Qt4 approach: Deriving a managed class (`ref class`) from a native interface is impossible -> compiler error. Writing another proxy class which uses managed objects through `auto_gcroot<ManagedCppQt^>` fails due to compiler errors regarding unknown Namespaces/Classes, etc. TL;DR: I cannot get it to work.